# How to implement read.zoo function correctly on my data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame of apple stock prices YTD as below file name appl.csv

```
Date Close.Last   Volume   Open   High    Low
1 12/20/2019     279.44 68972090 282.23 282.65 278.56
2 12/19/2019     280.02 24626950 279.50 281.18 278.95
3 12/18/2019     279.74 29024690 279.80 281.90 279.12
4 12/17/2019     280.41 28575800 279.57 281.77 278.80
5 12/16/2019     279.86 32081110 277.00 280.79 276.98
6 12/13/2019     275.15 33432810 271.46 275.30 270.93
```

I would like to transform the above data into a zoo time series  object so that I can use the power of time series analysis. I have tried writing the code as below, but not getting the results. Can anyone help me understand the mistake that I am committing in the code below.

```
mydata1 <- read.zoo("appl.csv",sep="," ,FUN,header =TRUE,format ="%m-%d-%y")
```

**r gives me the following results**

```
mydata1 <-read.zoo("appl.csv", format = "%m-%d-%y", tz = "", FUN = NULL,
+          regular = FALSE, index.column = 1, drop = TRUE, FUN2 = NULL,
+          split = NULL, aggregate = FALSE, read = read.table,sep=",",header =TRUE)
```

> Error in read.zoo("appl.csv", format = "%m-%d-%y", tz = "", FUN =
>   NULL,  :    index has 145 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 16 17
>   18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
>   49 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88
>   89 90 91 92 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 123
>   124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 143 144 145 146 147 148
>   149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 165 166 167 ...

Kindly let me know how to use read.zoo function

Comment: your file's Date field is in `%m/%d/%Y` format.

Answer (score 0):

The question did not show the input file format, only what it looks like after it was read in in a manner also not shown, so we can't be sure what you have but here are some comments based on the assumption that you have a csv file:

1. the dates shown in the question have slashes but the format specifies dashes in the code in the question.
2. The dates shown in the question have 4 digit years but the format used in the question specifies 2 digit years -- lower case y means 2 digits, upper case Y means 4 digits
3. `read.csv.zoo` is provided in the zoo package and should be used for csv files to save having to specify the `header=` and `sep=` arguments.
4. The filename shown in the question is `appl.csv` but the ticker of Apple stock is aapl, not appl.  We have used `appl.csv` below assuming that that really is your file name but you may want to change both the filename and the code.
5. `FUN` is written without a value.  In fact it is not needed at all here.  The default will do but at any rate you can't simply write an argument name without an equal sign and a value after it.

Keeping the above in mind we can write

```
read.csv.zoo("appl.csv", format ="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Also note that if you have already read it in as a data frame `DF` so that it looks like that shown in the question we can do this:

```
read.table(DF, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```